# creating file and load it in iframe

Tags: java, iframe, clob

Depending on the i/p of 2 textboxes, I want to extract a CLOB column from ORACLE  to a temporary text file & load the same text file to iframe. Once it got loaded completely, I'll delete the temp. text file. I'm extracting CLOB through java pgm & then putting the temp file path as src attribute to iframe. But the issue is that before completing the file creation, iframe loading is getting completed and showing file does not exist error. Any suggestions for this problem? I want to use single submit button for this entire procedure.

Answer (score 0):

your scenario shows that page is getting loaded before file is read/write.

you can add wait() or any Listener which can notify that file read write operation is done. then you redirect to that page.

please share the code snippet. then we can help you better.